# Why Python if function merge 2 conditions into one resulting syntax error?

Tags: python, if-statement

```
name1 = input("What is your name? \n")
name2 = input("What is their name? \n")

total1 = (name2+name1).count('t') + (name2+name1).count('r') + (name2+name1).count('u') + (name2+name1).count('e')
print("total1", total1)

total2 = (name2+name1).count('l') + (name2+name1).count('o') + (name2+name1).count('v') + (name2+name1).count('e')
print("total2", total2)

if (total1, total2) <= 10 or >= 90:
  print("Your score is", total1,total2, "you go together like coke and mentos.")
```

RESULT:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/PythonLoveCalculator.py", line 11
    if (total1, total2) <= 10 or >= 90:
                                  ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

What’s the simple explanation about this Syntax Error????

Comment: if (total1, total2) <= 10 or >= 90: needs to be if (total1, total2) <= 10 or (total1, total2) >= 90

Comment: But regardless of the pure syntax error, you cannot compare a tuple of two ints with a single int - `(1, 2) <= 10` does not make sense.

Comment: Also, what would comparing the tuple `(total1, total2)` to the integer `10` even mean?

Comment: @Beatdown How would you compare a tuple with an int?

Comment: you can't, my comment only addressed the need to be explicit with comparison

Comment: @Mime Probably not. `(9, 50) < (10, 10)` is `True`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to test multiple variables for equality against a single value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15112125/how-to-test-multiple-variables-for-equality-against-a-single-value)

Answer (score 0):

`SyntaxError` occurs because you use `>=` without a value before it:
More proper would be:

```
if (total1, total2)<=10 or (total1, total2)>=90:
    ...
```

But then you will get a `TypeError` because `<=` not supported between instances of `tuple` and `int'

It is not clear what are you trying to compare.
Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
if total1<=10 or total2>=90:
    ...
```